# Constructing a dataframe with multiple columns based on str conditions using a loop - python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a webscraped Twitter DataFrame that includes user location. The location variable looks like this:

```
2          Crockett, Houston County, Texas, 75835, USA
3                                   NYC, New York, USA
4                            Warszawa, mazowieckie, RP
5                                           Texas, USA
6                 Virginia Beach, Virginia, 23451, USA
7          Louisville, Jefferson County, Kentucky, USA
```

I would like to construct state dummies for all USA states by using a loop.

I have managed to extract users from the USA using

```
location_usa = location_df['location'].str.contains('usa', case = False)
```

However the code would be too bulky I wrote this for every single state.  I have a list of the states as strings.
Also I am unable to use

```
pd.Series.Str.get_dummies()
```

as there are different locations within the same state and each entry is a whole sentence.

I would like the output to look something like this:

```
   Alabama   Alaska  Arizona
1        0        0        1
2        0        1        0
3        1        0        0 
4        0        0        0
```

Or the same with Boolean values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.str.extract` to get a `Series` of the states, and then use `pd.get_dummies` on that `Series`. Will need to define a list of all 50 states:

```
import pandas as pd

states = ['Texas', 'New York', 'Kentucky', 'Virginia']
pd.get_dummies(df.col1.str.extract('(' + '|'.join(x+',' for x in states)+ ')')[0].str.strip(','))

   Kentucky  New York  Texas  Virginia
0         0         0      1         0
1         0         1      0         0
2         0         0      0         0
3         0         0      1         0
4         0         0      0         1
5         1         0      0         0
```

Note I matched on States followed by a `','` as that seems to be the pattern and allows you to avoid false matches like `'Virginia'` with `'Virginia Beach'`, or more problematic things like `'Washington County, Minnesota'`

If you expect mutliple states to match on a single line, then this becomes `.extractall` summing across the 0th level:

```
pd.get_dummies(df.col1.str.extractall('(' + '|'.join(x+',' for x in states)+ ')')[0].str.strip(',')).sum(level=0).clip(upper=1)
```

---

Edit:

Perhaps there are better ways, but this can be a bit safer as suggested by @BradSolomon allowing matches on `'State,( optional 5 digit Zip,) USA'`

```
states = ['Texas', 'New York', 'Kentucky', 'Virginia', 'California', 'Pennsylvania']
pat = '(' + '|'.join(x+',?(\s\d{5},)?\sUSA' for x in states)+ ')'

s = df.col1.str.extract(pat)[0].str.split(',').str[0]
```

#### Output: `s`

```
0           Texas
1        New York
2             NaN
3           Texas
4        Virginia
5        Kentucky
6    Pennsylvania
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

from Input

```
                                          col1
0  Crockett, Houston County, Texas, 75835, USA
1                           NYC, New York, USA
2                    Warszawa, mazowieckie, RP
3                                   Texas, USA
4         Virginia Beach, Virginia, 23451, USA
5  Louisville, Jefferson County, Kentucky, USA
6                California, Pennsylvania, USA
```

Comment: Given that you very may likely have a ton of stuff such as "California, Pennsylvania," it might not be a bad idea to concat USA next to the state name

Comment: @BradSolomon That's a good point. I think it's pretty tricky, since we'd lose Virginia given `Virginia, 23451, USA`. Could try to split on ',' and exact match the strings, but that's still not going to help `California, Pennsylvania`. If there is truly only one state per row, then it seems like picking the last match will be the safest.

Comment: Ah true.  Maybe throw an optional zip in between state/country.  Nice answer either way